# Not able to login via StackExchange iOS App [Facebook]

Tags: bug, login, ios-app, facebook

I can't login with my Facebook account to StackExchange via the iOS App.

I've tried about 10 times before posting this. Also tried to delete and re-download the app but nothing changes. Of course I've allowed the app to use my Facebook account.

Here's the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Same problem. I have official Facebook app installed, iOS8.3 on iPhone 6plus. Can login with Facebook on Safari on mobile with no problem so it's isolated to the app.